# Permission denied when pushing to remote repository: Error 403

Tags: git, github

I'm facing an issue while attempting to push my local changes to a remote repository on GitHub. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
remote: Permission to Projects/myWebsite.git denied to USER1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Projects/myWebsite@systemName-Latitude-ted URL returned error: 403
```

I have already authenticated with my GitHub account and have the necessary permissions to access the repository. However, I'm encountering this permission denial error.

Could you please help me understand the possible causes and suggest any solutions to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to confirm the below steps:-

1. You are authorized to make a commitment to the desired remote repo.
2. You have `git config` properly set up as per GitHub credentials.
3. You can try changing out your remote URL from
   `https://github.com/username/repo.git`
   to
   `git@github.com:username/repo.git`